How to determine the granularity of quantization?
I'm currently experimenting with Q-Diffusion for stable diffusion quantization using the following repository:
https://github.com/Xiuyu-Li/q-diffusion/tree/master
I am running the script with the following arguments: python scripts/txt2img.py --prompt "a puppy wearing a hat" --plms --cond --ptq --weight_bit 8 --quant_mode qdiff --no_grad_ckpt --split --n_samples 5 --resume --quant_act --act_bit 8 --sm_abit 16 --outdir <output_path> --cali_ckpt <quantized_ckpt_path>
My objective is to understand the granularity at which matrix operations are quantized within the model (e.g., per tensor, per token, per channel, etc.). I’ve tried placing breakpoints in the forward functions of QuantBasicTransformerBlock and other related classes to inspect the dimensions of the quantized operations, but I haven’t found clear indications of the granularity used.
My questions are:

What is the typical way to determine the granularity of quantization in a model like this?
Are there specific points in the code or specific variables that I should be inspecting to understand the granularity better?
Could there be any key details that I might be overlooking in this process?

Any guidance or suggestions on where to look or how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.
